# Generating random characters in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, random

I would like to generate a 16 character code

The code has 5 known characters
The code has 3 digits
The code must be random

What I did :

```
result1 = "NAA3U" + ''.join((random.choice(string.ascii_uppercase + string.digits) for codenum in range(11)))
```

Comment: Please tell us what errors/bugs do you see so we can help you.

Comment: i ve got no error but the code didn't contains 3 digit exactly

Answer (score 8, accepted):

One approach:

```
import random
import string

# select 2 digits at random
digits = random.choices(string.digits, k=2)

# select 9 uppercase letters at random
letters = random.choices(string.ascii_uppercase, k=9)

# shuffle both letters + digits
sample = random.sample(digits + letters, 11)

result = "NAA3U" + ''.join(sample)
print(result)
```

**Output** *from a sample run*

```
NAA3U6MUGYRZ3DEX
```

If the code needs to contain at least 3 digits, but is not limited to this threshold, just change to this line:

```
# select 11 uppercase letters and digits at random
letters = random.choices(string.ascii_uppercase + string.digits, k=11)
```

this will pick at random from uppercase letters and digits.

Comment: In your final bit of code, why did you change k=9 to k=11? That would make the code into an 18-character code rather than a 16-character one, right? You still have the two extra generated digits to make sure it ends up being at least three digits, after all.

Comment: @VincentOostelbos Notice that I'm selecting from `digits + letters` that have length 11, basically that line of code is shuffling the entire string.

Comment: Yes, but then there is no guarantee that (at least) two of these will be digits, right? Which, if you want to have at least 3 digits (but possibly more) would be a requirement. So I figured you would still have the string.digits, k=2 line as well (to make sure there are at least 3 digits), but then the total code would grow by 2.

Comment: I'm choosing 11 from 11 so there is a guarantee that 2 of them would be from `digits`

Comment: I might be confused. Aren't there 36 possible results in string.ascii_uppercase + string.digits (26 capitalized letters and 10 digits)? Wouldn't it be possible for it to choose 11 capitalized letters and 0 digits, in that case? (Or 10 capitalized letters and 1 digit, which still wouldn't be enough digits for the code, overall.)

Comment: The last line is supposed to replace `letters = ...` so you would still have the two digits in `digits` and the one already in the prefix (`3`) so at least 3 digits; even if there aren't any digits in `letters`

Comment: I understand that, but then you have the 5 known characters, the 2 digits, and the 11 letters+digits, for a total of 18 characters in the code. The original had 5 known characters, 2 digits, and 9 letters, for a total of 16 characters in the code (which was the requirement). So I think even with the change to string.ascii_uppercase + string.digits (which is fine), the k parameter should still be set to 9, not 11, to keep the total code length of 16 intact.

Answer (score 2):

You can add the remaining 2 digits at the end if it is fine for you like this

```
import random
import string

result1 = "NAA3U" + ''.join((random.choice(string.ascii_uppercase) for codenum in range(8))) + str(random.randint(10,99))

print(result1)

NAA3URYWMGIHG45
```

Comment: i expecting that my code contains only 3 digits inside

Comment: Let me know if my edit solves your issue

Comment: the code must be totaly random so no you don't resolve it but thanks a lot for your time

Comment: @Beluga: A tenth of the time your code will produce a 14 char string. I tested this and I got an example of: `NAA3UXGEUFWZX4`

Comment: Yeah my bad, it should be random.randint(10,99) instead of random.randint(1,99). Missed the extra zero

Comment: Yes, except you are limiting the number of `0` chars and `0` will only occur at the end.

Comment: @Biboune12 Dani's answer will work for you, adds the randomness we were missing

Comment: @quamrana Yeah true!

Answer (score 1):

You can use `random.choices` and `random.shuffle` then use `''.join` like below:

```
>>> import random
>>> import string

>>> def generate_rndm():
...    digit_char = random.choices(string.ascii_uppercase, k=9) + random.choices(string.digits, k=2)
...    random.shuffle(digit_char)
...    return "NAA3U" + ''.join(digit_char)
```

Output:

```
>>> generate_rndm()
'NAA3UTVQG8DT8NRM'

>>> generate_rndm()
'NAA3UCYBWCNQ45HR'

>>> generate_rndm()
'NAA3UIJP7W7DLOCQ'
```